# Nested many-to-many relationships in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have these two models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rarity = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    craftable = models.BooleanField()
```

and

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
     id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
     items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

Some Items have a Recipe because they are craftables, others don't because they are base Items.
Some Items needed to craft another item need to be created following a Recipe (they are nested, many times!)

Example:

> Item: Construction Material
>
> Recipe: [Steel, Chalk, **Reinforced Concrete**]
>
> ---
>
> Item: **Reinforced Concrete**
>
> Recipe: [Sand, Concrete, **Bricks**]
>
> ---
>
> Item: **Bricks**
>
> Recipe: [Resistant Stone, Concrete, Resin] <- All base Objects

How can i make a view that displays all the tree of the Items that allows me to make a certain Item?

> Result:
>
> - Construction Material
>
>   - Steel
>   - Chalk
>   - Reinforced Concrete
>
>     - Sand
>     - Concrete
>     - Bricks
>
>       - Resistant Stone
>       - Concrete
>       - Resin

I can't find a method to go as deep as i need into the relationships...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models don't show which recipe to use for a specific item. If you do something like this, then you can omit the `Recipe` model (edited to add `symmetrical = False`):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # django will create an id field automatically
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rarity = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)

    def is_base(self):
        return not self.ingredients

    def is_craftable(self):
        return not self.is_base()

    def build_recipe(self):
        recipe = []
        for ingredient in self.ingredients.all():
            recipe.append(ingredient.name)
            if ingredient.is_craftable():
                recipe.append(ingredient.build_recipe())
        return recipe
```

To display the nested recipes, you can use the built-in `unordered_list` filter in your template:

```
<h1>Recipe for {{ item.name }}</h1>
<ul>
    {{ item.build_recipe|unordered_list }}
</ul>
```

Comment: Before accepting this answer as good, i suggest you to change the second line of `build_recipe()` to: `for ingredient in self.ingredients.all()` because it threw me a "non-iterable" error.
Thanks a lot for your time!!!